# Use diagonal fill to eliminate 8-connectivity of the background in Python (similar to bwmorph diag in MATLAB)

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I'm looking for a way to connect 8-connected pixels in Python, similar to MATLAB's [bwmorph](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html) 'diag' function:

```
BW = bwmorph(BW, 'diag')
```

For example,

```
0  1  0           0  1  0
1  0  0    ->     1  1  0 
0  0  0           0  0  0
```

Thanks in advance!

Misha

Comment: maybe you will find from library `openCV` and `scikit-image` ?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a similar function in either library...

Answer (score 1):

That works, thanks! Here's the python code:

```
def bwmorphDiag(bw):
    # filter for 8-connectivity of the background
    f = np.array(([1, -1, 0],[-1, 1, 0],[0, 0, 0]),dtype = np.int)
    # initialize result with original image
    bw = bw.astype(np.int)
    res2 = bw.copy().astype(np.bool)
    for ii in range(4): # all orientations
        # add results where sum equals 2 -> two background pixels on the
        # diagonal with 2 foreground pixels on the crossing mini-anti-diagonal
        res2 = res2 | (ndimage.filters.convolve(np.invert(bw),f) == 2)
        f = np.rot90(f) # rotate filter to next orientation
    return res2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve the same result using simple image filtering. I did it in MATLAB, but it should be straight forward to do it in python as well:

```matlab
% random binary image
bw = rand(50) > 0.5;
% result using bwmorph(bw,'diag')
res1 = bwmorph(bw,'diag');
% filter for 8-connectivity of the background
f = [1 -1 0;-1 1 0;0 0 0];
% initialize result with original image
res2 = bw;
for ii = 1:4 % all orientations
    % add results where sum equels 2 -> two background pixels on the
    % diagonal with 2 foreground pixels on the crossing mini-anti-diagonal
    res2 = res2 | ( imfilter(double(~bw),f) == 2 );
    f = rot90(f); % rotate filter to next orientation
end
isequal(res2,res1) % yes
```

Answer (score 0):

I was actually looking for the same python equivalent, the `bwmorph('diag')` of MATLAB. But since I couldn't find it I eventually decided to code it. Please check the MATLAB help for `bwmorph` and the `diag` option to get further info about what it does.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage.morphology as smorph
import skimage.morphology as skm

class bwmorph:
@staticmethod
def diag(imIn):
    strl = np.array([
    [[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,0]],
    [[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,0]],
    [[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]],
    [[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]],
    [[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]],
    [[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,0,0]],
    [[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]],
    [[0,0,0],[1,0,1],[0,1,0]]
    ],dtype=np.uint8)
    bwIm = np.zeros(imIn.shape,dtype=int)
    imIn = np.array(imIn)
    imIn = imIn/np.max(np.max(imIn)) #normalizing to be added later
    for i in range(7):
        bwIm = bwIm + smorph.binary_hit_or_miss(imIn,strl[i,:,:])

    bwIm = ((bwIm>0) + imIn)>0
    return bwIm # out put is boolean
```

I used 'hit or miss' transform, with the structural element 'strl' defined at the beginning. I guess that's a classic way to do it.

Please watch the `@staticmethod` is you're running it on older python.
Usage example would be `bwmorph().diag(BinaryImage)`

All the best ;)